# Get Notified when question is answered

Tags: discussion, feature-request, notifications

Is it possible to get updated when an answer is added to a question which is asked by some other user.

Sometimes I see a question similar to what I want to ask and thus do not ask it. However I have to check it manually again and again to see if it is updated. Is there some feature which notifies me whenever an answer is added to question which interests me.

Comment: If there is no good answer yet you could raise a bounty

Answer (score 12):

As far as I know there is no existing functionality that will notify you when a question you are interested in is answered. The best you can currently do is "Favourite" the question so it appears in your profile and sort it by activity.

See this post about favourites: [How do favorite questions work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53585/how-do-favorite-questions-work)

The answer suggests that functionality will be added in the future to notify users of updates to the questions they star:

> Changes to the question will eventually (but do not currently) notify users who have favorited the question. Notifications will include comments to the question, edits, new answers, and edits to answers. This is a way to get updates on questions that you yourself didn't ask.

Comment: When will this functionality be added?